# App that allows to set tasks, due dates and also supports third-party calendars?

Tags: osx, project-management, calendar, educational, reminders

I'm looking for a **Mac app** for college that allows you to write in your homework, set due dates and also allows third-party calendars (ics preferably).

I've been searching for days to find one that does all three. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I use [iStudiez Pro](http://istudentpro.com/mac.php)

- Supports [Mac OS X](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/istudiez-pro/id402989379), [Windows](https://sites.fastspring.com/istudentpro/instant/istudiezproforwinpage) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/istudiez-pro/id310636441) (each version has to be bought seperately)
- Comes at a hefty price: $9,99 for the OS X and Windows versions, $2,99 for the iOS version
- Made for college/university
- Allows you to write in your homework (and essays, tests), set due dates, make notes, etc...
- Free cloud sync between different versions
- Offers two-way synchronisation with the built-in Calendar app (OS X)
- Has the ability to the export calendar

From the website <sub>*(yes, the English is atrocious sometimes, but I can assure you that the app itself is good and legit)*</sub>:

> ### The App to Organize Academic Life of Any Student. Syncs data with iOS and Windows versions.
>
> iStudiez Pro is the unique application for students which combines tracking schedule,
> homework and grades with a delightful user experience.
> Supports OS X Yosemite.
>
> #### Enjoy full Overview of classes and assignments every day
>
> Show all the events you have for the given day.
> This is real-time mode view tracks you schedule during the day giving you full overview
> of the classes or events you need to attend and assignments you need to complete
>
> #### All your homework and tasks in one place
>
> The app allows you to easily manage all your homework and assignments.
> Assigments view is a comprehensive tool to help you organize your academic work.
>
> #### Innovative schedule planner
>
> This is where your schedule starts. Plan and manage your courses and classes details, locations, instructors info, holidays and grades
>
> #### Free Cloud Sync
>
> iStudiez Pro syncs all the app data between Mac, iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad and Windows PC. Once input in the app on any of your devices, you data is momentarily synced to all of the others where iStudiez Pro is installed.
>
> #### Grades and GPA
>
> Use the app to calculate your grades and track your GPA progress. The GPA calculator is very comprehensive and works flawlessly with percents, points and letters grading scales.
>
> #### Catch your assignment, class or exam deadlines with smart notifications.
>
> You can set notifications for class times, exams and assignments. iStudiez Pro will remind you of when you need to get to class or complete an assignment based on the timed notification you set.
>
> #### Two-way integration with OS X Calendar app
>
> Calendar events can be shown in iStudiez Pro. Moreover, you can share the app's schedule to other calendar apps. Wish to share your schedule with your friends (parents?) or important someone? Go ahead!

Comment: Although the UI is completely horrible, I'll accept this answer as it provides everything (and more) that I've asked for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Another option

Google Docs and Google Calendar

1. Take notes in Google docs
2. Use Calendar and Tasks for the obvious
3. [Sync with iCal](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en)
4. Use the offline option to make sure you can access your files even when not connected to the internet

Answer (score 1):

When I went to law school in 2005, I was lucky enough that they gave all students a free copy of Microsoft Office, including [OneNote](http://www.onenote.com/), and because I used OneNote from the very beginning, it certainly helped my grades.

Besides taking notes, you can mark items as "to do". The "to do" box mark is directly in your notes, so you don't have to go to a separate page to make an item. It is simple to view all of your tasks and to sort them. You can set due dates for the tasks. You can create contacts and meetings.

I use OneNote 2007, and the free version of 2013 is not as powerful as 2007, but the paid version of 2013 looks better. It is simple and easy to sync with Outlook and other Office products, but since I use Windows, I don't know about iCalendar. I imagine there is a third-party sync tool somewhere.

Plus it syncs with your smart phone and other computers.

A blog post about [OneNote for Mac and iOS](http://blogs.office.com/2014/10/28/onenote-gets-even-better-mac-ios/).

Comment: I just have a difficult time using apps built by Microsoft. It's always a UX or UI issue for me. I'll give it a quick shot but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

#### I like **[Trello](https://trello.com/)**

- Allows you to create tasks
- Task can have due dates
- Also has apps for phones

The calendar thing isn't built-in but it seems like there might be ways to make it work:
[Integration with Calender](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37626/trello-google-calendar-iphone-calendar)

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a dedicated app for Mac which is what I'm looking for.